# Show indent size of 4 in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, indentation, sublimetext

I work on a project which is **2 spaces indented**.
I hate to work this way (IMO it makes the code very tight), **I usually use 4 spaces indentation** for all my projects.

Is it possible, in Sublime Text, to **show 4 spaces** for indentation **but keep the 2 spaces in the file** ?
I want to respect indent project convention.

I know how to change **tab_size** but here, I need a kind of "tab_size_appearance", or something like that :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't advice you any plugin to do what you want. But one possible solution is to reindent it using tabs ("Convert indentation To Tabs.") and then, when you're done editing, convert it back to two spaces.

P.S. I will give a link to this question to people that say that spaces are better than tabs ]:->